# Code to deliberately fail archive

Tags: ios, xcode

I know it's a bit of strange request, but I think it's worth a go.
I have a bit of a bad memory sometimes and just want to make my code fool-proof. I have some code that I don't want to distribute, but need for testing purposes.
Now, the last thing I want is to archive that uncommented code when forgetting about it. I have put a `#warning` flag in that code to help me remember, but I still get nervous I'll forget.
So, is there anything I can put alongside that code that will
a) Compile ok to run in-app but
b) Cause an archive to fail?

Again, I know it's kinda silly, but think it would be handy to have.
Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do your tests only in the Simulator, you could wrap the code in

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // put your testing code here
#else

#endif
```

Similarly, if you test only in Debug mode:

```
#if DEBUG
    // put your testing code here
#else

#endif
```

Archive builds are always done in Release mode, targeting an iOS device.